# Regex to remove non-adjacent duplicates in R

Tags: r, regex, stringr

Struggling to come up with a regex that removes duplicated characters in a string (i.e. only keeps the first occurrence)

In particular I want to remove all colons after the first appearance

```
s <- c("note: conducted by j:m",
       "location: made :n :apan",
       "date: 2010, ma: 3rd")
```

to become

```
note: conducted by jm
location: made in apan
date: 2010, ma 3rd
```

The best I can get to is

```
library(stringr)
str_remove(string = s, pattern = "(?<=:)(.*?):(.*)")
# [1] "note:"     "location:"     "date:"
```

EDIT:

The second best I can get is `"(:)(?=.*\1)"` on [regex.com](https://regexr.com/4us9s) - it identifies all but the last `:` (so sort of the reverse of what I want) but wont work in R, not sure why?

```
str_remove(string = s, pattern = "(:)(?=.*\1)")
# [1] "note: conducted by j:m"  "location: made :n :apan" "date: 2010, ma: 3rd"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [this](https://regex101.com/r/uJyPMm/1) pattern:

```
(?:^[^:]*:|\G(?!^))[^:]*\K:
```

Now, what I don't know, if this would be applicable to Ruby as I know near to nothing about it to be honest.

I did get [this](https://repl.it/repls/SuddenFinancialVariables) sample to work on a single string leaving me to think it *should* work =)

```
str = "location: made : in japan: or what:"
str.gsub(/(?:^[^:]*:|\G(?!^))[^:]*\K:/, '')
```

Comment: perfect... works using `gsub(x = s, pattern = "(?:^[^:]*:|\\G(?!^))[^:]*\\K:", replacement = "", perl = TRUE)`

Answer (score 2):

Try using `sub` in two steps here:

```
first <- sub("^(.*?:).*", "\\1", s)
second <- sub("^.*?:", "", s)
second <- sub(":", "", second, fixed=TRUE)
out <- paste0(first, second)
out

[1] "note: conducted by jm"  "location: made in apan" "date: 2010, ma 3rd"
```

**Data:**

```
s <- c("note: conducted by j:m",
       "location: made in :apan",
       "date: 2010, ma: 3rd")
```

The approach here is to capture each string up to and including the first colon in one variable, then capture the remainder of each string in a second variable.  Then, we remove colons only from the second variable, and finally we paste the two pieces together to generate the expected output.

Note that a more concise way to do this would be to use `sub` or maybe `str_replace_all` with a callback function, but the syntax is not so straightforward.

Comment: looking for a more concise way to do this, i.e. a straight regex... on some lines I have more than two `:` and i am running on tens of thousands of lines, so by creating intermediate objects i am worried about the speed - perhaps unnecessarily?

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer, you might find some way to do the regex replacement using a one-liner with a callback function.  _But_, even that wouldn't necessarily be any more efficient than the solution in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, "*Look-Behind pattern matches must have a bounded maximum length.*"

So, [Tim's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60349282/3817004) is probably the way to go by

1. splitting each string in two parts,
2. remove all `:` from the second part, and
3. re-concatenate first and modified second part

Here is a one-liner implementation:

```
library(stringr)
sapply(str_split(s, "(?<=:)", n = 2L), function(x) paste0(x[1L], str_remove_all(x[-1L], ":")))
```

which returns

> ```
> [1] "note: conducted by jm"    "location: made n apan"    "date: 2010, ma 3rd"      
> [4] "no double colon"          "test1:"                   "test2: colon1 colon2 end"
> ```

for an enhanced sample character vector (including a few edge cases):

```
s <- c("note: conducted by j:m",
       "location: made :n :apan",
       "date: 2010, ma: 3rd",
       "no double colon",
       "test1::::",
       "test2: colon1: colon2: end")
```

Answer (score 0):

By the look of the problem stated, regexes seem to be too complicated a way to do this. Isn't a non-regex way much simpler? Like this one:

```
for s in ss:
    it = re.subn( ":", "#", s, count=1 ) #Replace the first ":" with "#" to distinguish it from others
    print( it[0].replace( ":", "" ).replace( "#", ":" ) ) #Remove remaining ":"s and bring back the original
```

Of course, if you prefer a regex-based solution for some other reason, this won't do. (Also, the solution given is in Python and not R, you may have noticed.)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Good point. If the nature of the input data is known, we can choose a character or characters accordingly. Eg, if I know that ```#$#$^&^#$``` is never going to come in the input string, I can choose that instead of ```#```.